# How to pass an ID parameter to DataTables to limit results based on that ID

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, model-view-controller, datatables

Within my application, I have a DataTable set that returns a list of Products from **Index**, along with a button to navigate the Products **View** to display all relevant information. I am able to display the information in basic tables, as seen in the images, but would rather DataTables for the added functionality.

Within this **View** I want to also display a list of locations they are stored, but only for that **ProductID**. Whilst I can retrieve all, and if I hard code the ProductID within the call - I cannot pass it from the View.

My **GetAllStorageProducts** is in my **ProductController**:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAllStorageProducts()
        {
            List<StorageProduct> productList = _unitOfWork.StorageProduct.GetAll(includeProperties:"StorageLocation,Product").ToList();
            return Json(new { data = productList });
        }
```

And the script that it calls **storageProduct.js**

```
var dataTable;
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        ajax: { url: '/Product/GetAllStorageProducts' },
        columns: [
            { data: 'storageLocation.storageLocationName', "width": "20%" },
            { data: 'localQtyOnHand', "width": "25%" }
        ]
    });
}
```

My **View** ion the ProductController

```
public IActionResult View(int? ProductId)
        {
            ProductVM productVM = new()
            {
                Product = new Product(),
                StorageProduct = _unitOfWork.StorageProduct.GetAll(includeProperties: "StorageLocation,Product")
                .Where(u => u.ProductId == ProductId).ToList(),
                ProductValues = _unitOfWork.ProductValues.GetAll(includeProperties: "StorageLocation,Product")
                .Where(u => u.ProductId == ProductId).ToList()
            };

            if (ProductId == null || ProductId == 0)
            {
                //CREATE
                return View(productVM);
            }
            else
            {
                //UPDATE
                productVM.Product = _unitOfWork.Product.Get(u => u.ProductId == ProductId);
                /*Will return the details about the product in JSON*/
                //return Json(new { data = productVM });
                return View(productVM);
            }
        }
```

**ProductVM**

```
    public class ProductVM
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<StorageProduct> StorageProduct { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProductValues> ProductValues { get; set; }
    }
```

This returns:

[image]

But what I want is:

[image]

I have tried altering the ProductVM to include an IActionResult and passing in the **GetAllStorageProducts**(productID) but that failed to work. I have also tried passing a parameter through the **storageProduct.js** but that has also failed to work.

Is this achieveable?